# How to upload layer's metadata in Geonode using REST API?

Tags: geoserver, metadata, rest, geonode

I want to upload Geonode Metadata to Geonode using a REST API. I have succesfully created my own custom template for my layer at Editing Tools> Wizard>Dataset Attributes, but I would like to do the same job via REST API. Is it possible?

Comment: Any luck in the end?

Comment: Hello. I solved this issue by writing my own code in Python that does a POST request and uploads the metadata for the specific layer. I used the Inspection tool that is embedded in any browser and found out the structure of the POST request that is sent when I update the metadata of a layer in Geonode. Then, as I said I created some code that does the same thing in python.